# After Xubuntu 10.04 to 10.10 upgrade, my keyboard shortcuts no longer work

Tags: xubuntu

I upgraded my xubuntu 10.04 workstation to 10.10 and the upgrade went ok, apart from the fact that now my keyboard shortcuts don't work.

The precious one for me is "run program" which is usually bound to Alt+F2. Ctrl+Esc usually brings up the Applications menu, that's not working either.

I've checked all my settings in settings manager and everything looks normal. Also done some googling but to no avail.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: try remapping the key shortcuts. I think they changed the key names to support left and right ctrl and alt keys.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried opening a terminal and starting the xfce4 manager helper directly?

```
xfce4-settings-helper
```

Comment: Because this came up today for me as well: `xfce4-settings-helper` is now apparently called `xfsettingsd` in the recent versions. The problem still sometimes appears, and (re)starting xfsettingsd will solve it.