# Keyboard shutcuts not working on Xubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xubuntu

My keyboard shortuts no longer work (FOr example Super T for termanal super r for run etc)

Ive found a few help threads online including here) 
[After Xubuntu 10.04 to 10.10 upgrade, my keyboard shortcuts no longer work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62140/after-xubuntu-10-04-to-10-10-upgrade-my-keyboard-shortcuts-no-longer-work)

I get "Command not found" for that

Ive deleted my ./cache/sessions/*

Ive reset my keyboard shortcuts any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it could be bug [#1292290 - Window manager keybindings don't work after reboot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1292290). A workaround is mentioned there:

```
I found a workaround: clear before reassign!

To make a shortcut to work ok, select an action you want to reassign and click 'Clear' button until it will really empty. Sometime if there is some (hidden?) duplicates, you will still see some shortcut (the same or different), even you clicked 'Clear' button. In this case just click the button again. Since the action shortcut is really empty, just assign your custom one as usual, and it will work ok :)
```

And

```
Someone on #xubuntu or #ubuntustudio (can't remember) mentioned a workaround for this:

You simply have to delete the current key mapping twice before setting a new one. Then the new mapping will be stored in the config.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Found out that when I go to Setting - Settings manager - Session and startup - Advanced and turn on Launch Gnome services at startup, all of the shortcuts begin working again. What confused the issue: every time I logged in, Orca and Onboard would turn on. Seems to be a bug. As I don't use these, I uninstalled them. Then everything went fine.
Of course, the question is, why do I need gnome services for this? I would rather keep them off, as they seem to slow things down. After all, the reason I have xubuntu is to keep my old machine running up to speed.